# Adding HC-SR04 ultrasonic sensor to the board

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, pins, wires

I would like to add three more HC-SR04 sensor

Currently I have combined the Arduino UNO R3 with the AR 293d(refer to below graph), and pluged in one HC-SR04 sensor to the SRO4 hole at the left top corner. **So I need to find the holes for t3 more sensor**.

[image]

[image]

I have done some research already , for the connection , found more document

```
HC-SR04 Arduino
Vcc     +5V
Trig    GPIO
Echo    GPIO
GND     GND
```

[image]

The questions are ,

1) From the above graph, is that mean I can only add two more sensor to the board , since there are only 2 more 5V, GND , 12 , 13 pins (at the top and bottom holes)

2) How can I connect them separately ? That means, what I need to connect from sensor to the board?

3) If I need other board eg. breadboard to connect them, How should I connect sensor to breadboard and how can I connect it with the main board(AR 293d)?

Thanks a lot for helping. Any answer is useful for me

Comment: Welcome to Arduino SE! Can you please clarify how this question is different than the linked question in the comment above? Thanks!

Comment: Only pin12, trig needs to be unique. You can only work with one US at a time, all the echo pins can be combined to one. So for 3 sensors, you will need 4 pins, plus vcc/gnd

Comment: This question is about using multiple Ultra sonics. the linked to question about generic breadboarding.